# send multiple checkbox value in loop to servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets, checkbox

I have a servlet class with doget() that uses for loop to fill the checkbox for various users. For eg it will fill the user Rahul with checkbox read and execute based on the some criteria and it will fill user Subh with checkbox full control and the remaining boxes remain unchecked. Now the user on the web page unchecks or check the boxes for each user to modify it. Now how I'm supposed to pass the change checkbox value for each user to a different function.

```
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
       {
         String[] parts = prop[i].split("\\\\");
         arr[i] = parts[0];
         pw.println("<tr><td>");
         pw.println(parts[0]+"\\ "+parts[1]);       //user's firstname\lastname
         pw.println("</td><td>");
         if(parts[2].contains("Full Control"))
         {
             pw.println("<label><input type='checkbox' value='FullControl' checked='checked'/>Full Control </label>"
                    + "<label><input type='checkbox' value='Read' checked='checked'/>Read </label>"
                    + "<label><input type='checkbox' value='Write' checked='checked'/>Write </label>"
                    + "<label><input type='checkbox' value='Execute' checked='checked'/>Execute</label>");
         } 
         else
         {
            pw.println("<label><input type='checkbox' value='FullControl'/>Full Control</label>");
            if(parts[2].contains("Read")){
                pw.println("<label><input type='checkbox' value='Read' checked='checked'/>Read</label>");
            }
            if(parts[2].contains("Execute")) {
                pw.println("<label><input type='checkbox' value='Execute' checked='checked' />Execute</label>");
            }
            if(parts[2].contains("Write")) {
                pw.println("<label><input type='checkbox' value='Write' checked='checked' />Write</label>");
            }
         }
```

I want to pass this details in a method modifyPermission(firstname, checkboxValue, allow\deny) to modify it for each user for each permission. Something like this

```
obj.modifyACL(username, accessType, allow\deny);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an HTML "form" that surrounds the checkboxes. Add distinct `name` attribute to each checkbox. And add a button the user can push to send the form.

The generated HTML should look like:

```html
<form action="modifyAcl" method="post">
<label><input type='checkbox' name="fullControl" value='FullControl' checked='checked'/>Full Control</label>
...all your other checkboxes...

<input type="submit" value="Modify ACL" />
</form>
```

When the user pushes the button, the browser sends the values of the form elements in a POST request back to the server

Servlet would then receive the request in the `doPost` method. In this method you extract the form data from request parameters, and then call your modifyACL method.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {
  
  boolean fullControlChecked =  "FullControl".equals(request.getParameter("fullControl"));
  // extract other information to set the obj, username, accessType, and allowDeny variables

  obj.modifyACL(username, accessType, allowDeny);
}
```

Comment: I tried the same. I provided name attribute value as firstname+Fullcontrol for each user and it worked.